# Complex interclass policy shadowed by abstract class

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am implementing some game in C++, however technically it doesn't matter as long as I have strict OOP/Design patterns problem.

> I have a containter of abstract type MapObject. Lets call him MO.
>
> Inside MO I have classes that extends MapObject: TankX, TankY, Bullet, LineBullet, Terrain etc.

I need MO as long as I do a lot of *stuff* with its members.

*Stuff* includes collision detection.

In game loop I look for collisions following way:

```
foreach(MO A)
  foreach(MO B)
    somehow check collision policy and if A may collide B in theory, check this out in practice
    take coords of A, B and detect collision
```

The problem is, collision policy is very complex.

For example: LineBullet can collide with TankX and Terrain but not with TankY. Bullet can collide both Tanks but can not collide Terrains. etc. etc.

In reality, I have more classes so there are more complex examples.

Well, in nested foreach loops above what I have is MO A and MO B. I don't know what are they exactly; TankY, TankX, LineBullet or whatever. What I only have is common interface to access them. Thats ok.

**The question is: how to account collision policy inside these nested loops the right way ?**

My temporary solution is so ugly, I cannot accept this.

What I do is as follows:

- in MO I have polymorphic function getID() that returns int
- every class like TankX, TankY, Bullet etc. implements getID() and returns some hardcoded unique ID
- I have also object PM of class PolicyManager. This class contains collisionability matrix (all cases). So it knows global collision policy.

In nested loops:

```
foreach(MO A)
  foreach(MO B)
    if(PM->checkCollisionPolicy(A->getID(),B->getID()))
      start to detect collision
```